# How to measure power consumed in each clock cycle in C (using ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: 16.04, powertop

I actually want to measure the power consumed while doing each 64 bit multiplications and additions on Intel i7-6700 processor. For that purpose I need to know power consumed per clock cycle , I'm using desktop, so I think Powerstat / PowerTop won't work ? Are there any other available options ? Please help!
Thanks